# keydown event is not working on editable texbox on grid in c# windows application

Tags: c#

I want to add a new row in the grid when i press a enter key in a texbox in the gridview

```
private void dgReceipt_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgReceipt.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl txtcontrol = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
        if (txtcontrol != null)
        {
            txtcontrol.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(txtcontrol_KeyPress);
        }
    }
}

private void txtcontrol_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            dgReceipt.Rows.Add(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the `txtcontrol_KeyPress` event handler?  When you say not working what do you mean?  Error? Nothing happens?

Comment: When you say, add a row, do you mean a new row in the gridview or a new row in the textbox?  If it's the textbox then just use a multi-line textbox.

Comment: I take it the 6th element in the DataGridView really is a DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl? (Columns is zero based) and that therefore the handler is actually added?  BTW since dgReceipt_EditingControlShowing is called many times, you need a check that the event does not already have a handler, otherwise you will have multiple handlers!